# Show correlation in Scatter Plot in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have data that has details of multi observations submitted everyday, I want to show each observation as a dot in the graph to show the correlation, currently it sum up all the records in one dot for each date. Is that possible in Powerbi?

[image: Scatter Plot]

Also, how can we add a line to show the correlation?